# I can't execute custom query in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem, I write a query like this

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id";
```

When I run it directly in my database, there is no problem and it work and select custom rows from wp_posts table, but I can't run it in my code, and code show no results

```
global $wpdb;    
$query = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    $query->the_post();
    the_title();
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

when you use $wpdb->get_results() you get an array of the rows returned. You're not getting the actual wordpress post object so you can't use the_post(). [see here for get_results](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results)

if you want to query for posts i suggest using [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) or [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). it will look something like this:

```
// The Query
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$query` you have holds an array of results. Do a `print_r()` on it to view its values.

On the other side, you're using `$query->the_post();` and `the_title();` which can only be used inside the [wordpress loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Solution:

```
#after your query:
foreach($query as $result){
  echo get_the_title($result->ID) . '<br />';
}
```